# How to post multiple models in one post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, models

I have the following scenario of adding a product, I want the user to enter some SKU information for that product as well. The product and sku have a one to one relationship and I want to post two models/objects in one create action post. How would one achieve this?

The action signature would look like this

```
public ActionResult Create(Product product, Sku sku)
```

what would my razor markup need to look like in order to achieve this? Would I need two forms? Or is there something built into MVC that I haven't seen yet?

Comment: a new view model ? `ProductSkuViewModel`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need another model which contains all your required stuff like this:

```
public Class SomeClassName
{
 public Product product{get;set;}
 public Sku sku{get;set;}
}
```

and then you need to send it instead

```
public ActionResult Create(SomeClassName data)
```

Answer (score 2):

Best practise is to create a view model that contains all the data you need to send/receive, your view would reference that view model along with your controller and then in the controller you handle the logic to save both parts of the data as needed.